# How to write a python script to call a API and print the results retrieved from the API

Tags: php, python, api

I am a beginner and new to coding. I have an API in php gives the some meteo data retrieved from a meteo station. i want to have a python script which will call the API and print the results from the API in a file. Please suggest me the right coding approach. The API is:
http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={"token":"pcss","id":303,"operacja":"odczyt_doba"}

Comment: If you're a beginner you should start with the basics. The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is perfect for this kind of situation. More, you should decide between PHP and Python.

Comment: i would also recommend looking at the requests library http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `urllib2` library (for python 2) to fetch the data from the API. It could look something like this:

```
import urllib2
import csv  

        # API url
        url = "your API url"

        # open the api url
        response = urllib2.urlopen(str(url))

        data = response.read()

        # write the results in a csv file
        with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
```

or if JSON

```
import json
import urllib2  

        # API url
        url = "your API url"

        # open the api url
        response = urllib2.urlopen(str(url))

        data = json.load(response) 

        # write the results in a csv file
        with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
```

I have not used it with python 3 but I do not think there is a lot of changes.

Comment: Thanks @Phillis Peters. What if i want to parse the data retrieved from the API and then make the resultant csv file. I mean i want to have only the multiple values and leave out the rest.

Comment: You should filter the data you want with the url, that way you do not fetch data you do not need. The API documentation should have guidelines on that. You can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxofwuWTs7c)